# PyQt5.QtWidgets module not found when pyqt is installed with Anaconda

Tags: python, pyqt, anaconda, pyqt5

I can import PyQt5 but I cannot import from PyQt5.QtWidgets when I install pyqt in a conda environment.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling with conda and that did not solve the problem.
If I install with pip in a regular virtual environment instead of with Anaconda then it works.

This is the code:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
```

This is the error:

```sh
$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'
```

Comment: How did you install PyQt5?

Comment: I installed with `conda install pyqt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a path problem. I had installed Homebrew after Anaconda and /usr/local/bin was in front of $HOME/anaconda3/bin in $PATH, so Homebrew Python was being called instead of Anaconda Python.